# virsh - list all mac addresses for all network interfaces of any type

Tags: qemu, libvirt, virsh

I'm trying to identify one of a few dozen virtual machines by a given mac address (52:54:00:: OUI, mapping to QEMU),

the following lists the dhcp table from the NAT based virtual machine adapters, however many of these virtual machines have host device macvtap adapters.

```
virsh net-dhcp-leases default
```

the macvtap adapters mac addresses are shown in virt-manager for each network interface, whats the virsh command to query all network adapter's mac addresses?

Answer (score 3):

You can use virsh to do this

```
# virsh domiflist vmname
```

For all the VMs use;

```
# for i in `virsh list --all --name`; do echo $i; virsh domiflist $i; done
```

Comment: These are `exactly` the same commands that the answer from a few months ago uses, although I have to agree your `for` is much cleaner than that bash spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an obvious way to do this in virsh natively, but I enumerated it with the following shell command:

```
virsh list --all --name \
    | while read line; do ( \
        virsh domiflist $line \
        | sed 's,^,'$line': ,' \
    ); done \
| grep 52:54:00:<my_mac_suffix>
```